# SQL Server Like Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

How can we search multiple fields in a table using the `like` operator?

Eg :

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMP 
WHERE ENAME LIKE ('%SCOTT%');
```

What if I want to search for multiple columns like `'%SCOTT%'` OR `'%ADAMS%'` etc in a single query without using multiple like clause?

Comment: You can't do it if you have an `OR` logic, there must be multiple `LIKE`s. May I ask why don't you want to use multiple `LIKE` clauses when it's obviously the right way of querying to get what you want?

Comment: You'll use multiple `LIKE` clauses and like it. T-SQL is not a very flexible language. Any "workaround" you devise for this is likely to have worse performance. If you need additional flexibility in searching text, see if [full-text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search) is possibly of use.

Comment: It feels like there is some additional context as to why you don't want to use multiple LIKE clauses. Are you looking for brevity in syntax? Or is there a more complex requirement that you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can use `LIKE '%[SA][CD][OA][TM][TS]%' ` but this will also match `SCAMS`

Comment: I don't want to use multiple LIKE because Its dynamic. I don't know how many search string will come. My search parameter is like "Reddit, Twitter, MarketWatch, etc...."

Answer (score 0):

As variant ))

```
SELECT e.*
FROM EMP e
JOIN (VALUES('SCOTT'),('ADAM')) k(Name) ON e.ENAME LIKE CONCAT('%',k.Name,'%')
```

If you use SQL Server 2016 or higher you also can use `string_split`

```
SELECT e.*
FROM EMP e
JOIN (SELECT value Name FROM string_split('SCOTT,ADAM',',')) k ON e.ENAME LIKE CONCAT('%',k.Name,'%')
```

The second variant is good if you use names as a varchar parameter in a procedure

```
CREATE PROC FindEmpByNames
  @Names varchar(200)
AS
    SELECT e.*
    FROM EMP e
    JOIN (SELECT value Name FROM string_split(@Names,',')) k ON e.ENAME LIKE CONCAT('%',k.Name,'%')
GO
```

Test

```
EXEC FindEmpByNames 'SCOTT,ADAM'
```

You also can use values from a database table

```
CREATE TABLE ParamNames(Name varchar(10))

INSERT ParamNames(Name)VALUES
('SCOTT'),
('ADAM')
-------------
SELECT e.*
FROM EMP e
JOIN ParamNames k ON e.ENAME LIKE CONCAT('%',k.Name,'%')
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working after "ALTER DATABASE coinfeed SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130"

Comment: @Shailesh Kalasariya - Check `Compatibility level` in `Database Properties -> Options`. It must be `SQL Server 2016` as minimum.

Comment: It is working on my local server. But it is not working on my live server because I am getting error like "Valid values of the database compatibility level are 90, 100, or 110."

Comment: @Shailesh Kalasariya - I think it's SQL Server 2012. It haven't got `string_split` function yet. Is the first variant only working?

Comment: SELECT e.*
FROM EMP e
JOIN (VALUES('SCOTT'),('ADAM')) k(Name) ON e.ENAME LIKE CONCAT('%',k.Name,'%')

How can I use values from database table?

Comment: @Shailesh Kalasariya - I've added it into my answer.

Comment: Thanks. You posted exactly which I want. Thanks.

Comment: @Shailesh Kalasariya - I've modified the last query - `SELECT e.* FROM EMP e JOIN ParamNames k ON e.ENAME LIKE CONCAT('%',k.Name,'%')`. It don't need a subquery here.

Comment: @Shailesh Kalasariya - Could you confirm my answer?